# Magento 1.9 - Add currency suffix to Base URL

Tags: magento-1.9, currency, switcher

I am using default currency switcher, want to add currency ISO code suffix with base URL. Like http://www.example.com/ to http://www.example.com/currency=USD when switch currency.

Any help?